# Proper way to get separate subtypes to cooperate if each has unique properties

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, subtyping

I think this is more of a conceptual *object oriented programming* problem than a technical one, I have a few ideas the I could use, but each feels more like a hacky workaround rather than easily extendable solutions. I'm trying to figure out the more or less accepted way to resolve this type of problem.

Say I have an interface `Scalar`

```java
public interface Scalar {

    public Scalar add(Scalar addend);

    ...
```

with two concrete implementations: `RealScalar` which represents decimal values and `RationalScalar` which represents fractions

```java
public class RealScalar implements Scalar {

    private double value; 

    public RealScalar(double input)
    {  
        value=input;
    }
    ...
```

```java
public class RationalScalar implements Scalar {

    private int numerator,denominator;

    public RationalScalar(int numerator, int denominator)
    {  
        this.numerator=numerator;
        this.denominator=denominator;
    }
    ...
```

I use a factory class `ScalarFactory` to instantiate new scalars as a way of making the implementation indifferent to what type of `Scalar` is currently being referred to.

If each subtype has properties(and methods) unique to that subtype (in this case `value` for `RealScalar` and `numerator`,`denominator` for `RationalScalar`) and the java compiler can't know ahead of time what the runtime type of Scalar will be, thus causing the implemented methods (declared in the parent interface) such as:

```java
    @Override
    public RealScalar multi(Scalar multiplicand)
    {
    if (getClass()!=multiplicand.getClass())
            multiplicand=multiplicand.toReal();

    return new RealScalar(value*(
        (RealScalar)multiplicand).getValue());
    }
```

to lead to compile time errors, since `toReal` is a method of the child class `RationalScalars`:

```
./RealScalar.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
            multiplicand=multiplicand.toReal();
                                     ^
  symbol:   method toReal()
  location: variable multiplicand of type Scalar
```

What is the proper way to get these subclasses to cooperate?

EDIT: I actually got this working by adding a convert function to the interface that took a class type as an argument, and then implemented that in each of the subtypes. While that works, I'm still not sure if that is conceptually correct. On one hand, the ability to convert to other types of values is something you would want from an object meant to be a mathematical entity, on the other this makes the subtypes slightly interdependent.

### Possible Solutions

**1) include a method `convert` in the subtypes which takes a Scalar and produces a scalar of the child type.**

the problem with this is subtypes are supposed to be relatively independent, and under normal circumstances have similar properties. This requires each class be explicitly coded to manipulate the unique properties of other subtypes, and if more scalars are implemented could lead to a growing base of hacky workarounds necessary in each `Scalar` implementation.

**2) make value a list of generic Numbertypes in the interface**

This is both ugly and problematic, as the generic numbertypes don't support mathematical operations, meaning that the values will have to be stored as generic numbers then cast as primitives for every operation, which would likely be too computationally expensive for the use case (polynomial calculator)

**3) store value for `RationalScalar` as decimal and only convert to a fraction for display.**

Definitely not the direction I want to go given how difficult to keep the decimal number in a format that is easily converatble to a fraction that isn't in the form `2345883/4232569`

Comment: In which class is `public RealScalar multi(Scalar multiplicand)` declared? Why don't you use `instanceof` operator? Edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I edited to make it a bit more clear. `multi` was declared in the interface, and `instanceOf`, while making the code shorter just leads to the same problem: making the code work for every type of `Scalar` implementation. If I started adding more implementations of scalars, the checks for conversion would have to be hard coded for each `Scalar` type, in each `Scalar` implementation. While that is a working solution, it's seems to be the kind of thing OOP and inheritance was conceptualized to avoid: interdependence between subclasses that makes future extension difficult